# Asp.Net MVC: Handling error thrown in an error view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have set up error handling in MVC (4) and it works great. I've registered HandleErrorAttribute in global.asax and set the apropriate configuration in web.config.
However, If I redirect to the error view and the error view itself throws an error, I am redirected back to the error page - endlessly. The error is happening in the layout and the layout managed outside of the application. If there is an error in the layout I'm hosed. How can I prevent this? What sort of error handling fallback should I use? Using a different layout is not an option.

Comment: When the error in the view occurs, can you debug and verify that `Application_Error` is hit in global.asax?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it. Give it a try:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
    //Retrieving the last server error
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();    

    //Erases any buffered HTML output
    Response.Clear();

    //Declare the exception
    var httpException = exception as HttpException;

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error"); //Adding a reference to the error controller

    if (httpException == null)
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "ServerError"); //Non HTTP related error handling
    }
    else //It's an Http Exception, Let's handle it.
    {
        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            //these are special views to handle each error
            case 401:
            case 403:
                //Forbidden page.
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Forbidden");
                break;
            case 404:
                //Page not found.
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotFound");
                break;       
            case 500:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "ServerError");
                break;
            default:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
                break;
        }
    }

    //Pass exception details to the target error View.
    routeData.Values.Add("message", exception);

    //Clear the error on server.
    Server.ClearError();

    //Avoid IIS7 getting in the middle
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
    IController errorController = new ErrorController();
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(
         new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

Comment: I spent an afternoon figuring out a bug until I found that `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` fix.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ahmed! What will happen if your ServerError action threw an exception?

Comment: To Graham: I had that happen to me too :)